# Making a rough topo landscape smooth

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Using OpenTopoMap and Blender, I've recreated a landscape in 3D. The height difference is in rough 10m steps. Now I want to smooth the space between these steps:

[image]

Using smooth shading and the edge split modifier, the result is okay at first, but it still doesn't look too good:

[image]

Using Subdivision Surface, the result is even worse:

[image]

Can you think of alternative ways to smoothen out the topo?

Comment: Are your faces simply ngons between neighbouring contour lines?

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode select all vertices and press "smooth vertex" in the tool shelf (T). The tool has some adjustable parameters (search in the bottom left of the tool panel, press the little plus icon if not visible.

[image]